# How to make posts from like button public by default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-like

I have an unusual problem with my website, which has been built using Ruby on Rails technology. Whenever I click "Like" button under any post on my webpage, the post is supposed  to be shared on my facebook profile like posts from 9gag. The problem is that by default, this post's visibility on my facebook profile is set that only I can see it and I want the post to be (by default) visible for all my friends. How can I do that? I couldn't find anything helpful on google about this case.

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my website. For some reason, the Facebook App that you create to add widgets to your website sets its privacy default in your profile to "only me".
This only happens for the user that creates the App (maybe to avoid making your first tests and debug public) : in fact, I noticed that other users can share articles publicly without changing any settings.
To change it, just go to privacy settings in your Facebook profile: there you will see your website preference under Applications. Change it from "Only me" to "friends" or "public"